# Why querySelector show 2 different way of result in Edge console?

Tags: javascript, console, getelementbyid, queryselector

I have a div element by id "test", and here is my javascript code:

```js
const test = document.querySelector("#test");
console.log(test);
```

Then I open the console of Edge, but the result show 2 different way when I refresh the page, and I cannot figure the pattern out. Just like the GIF below:
[image]

Along with click the refresh button, the `console.log` result is changed sometimes. but the code is never changed.

What should I do if I always want the result below?

[image]

Comment: Potentially [`console.dirxml()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/dirxml_static)?

Comment: What is the code that results in "result 2"? The *same* code? How is it being used? It's not at all clear what this question is asking.

Comment: I tried `dirxml()` just now, result is mostly result 1 , and  occasionally result 2.

Comment: You won't get different output from the same input. This means you're either using a different command in the console each time, or the HTML/JS changes.

Comment: I have changed "result 1" to "screenshot 1", it may more readable.

Comment: Are you basically saying that you're getting different outputs depending on if the console is open/closed? I've seen similar behaviour in the past.