# Why sometimes I get the element itself and sometimes I get an object in DOM Console using document.querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, dom, console

So these are my codes:

```js
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel')
console.log(panels[0])

panels.forEach(panel => {
    panel.addEventListener('click', () => {
        removeActiveClasses()
        panel.classList.add('active')
    })
})

function removeActiveClasses() {
    panels.forEach(panel => {
        panel.classList.remove('active')
    })
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli&display=swap');

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    width: 90vw;
}

.panel {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 80vh;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    flex: 0.5;
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 700ms ease-in;
}

.panel h3{
    font-size: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

.panel.active{
    flex: 5;
}

.panel.active h3{
    opacity: 3;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in 0.4s;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .container{
        width: 100vw;
    }

    .panel:nth-of-type(4),
    .panel:nth-of-type(5) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Expanding Cards</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel active" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558979158-65a1eaa08691?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80')">
            <h3>
                Explore The World
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572276596237-5db2c3e16c5d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80')">
            <h3>
                Wild Forest
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1353&q=80')">
            <h3>
                Sunny beach
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551009175-8a68da93d5f9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1351&q=80')">
            <h3>
                City on Winter
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549880338-65ddcdfd017b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80')">
            <h3>
                Mountains - Clouds
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And when I console.log the panels[0] I receive sometimes the whole element itself:

[image]

And sometimes I get this on the console:

[image]

And when I expand the [first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nBWC.png) I get this:

[image]

This is when I press F5, the console switches between both results and I don't understand why, thank you in advance.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using opera 107.0.5045.21

Comment: Can you try running the code on another browser. Maybe Opera has an issue

Comment: Browser consoles do what they do because they're trying to be helpful. Their behavior does not really mean anything for the correct or incorrect behavior of your code.

Comment: Similar recent question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77946524/5648954 - I've noticed this behaviour in Chrome as well for a few years.

Comment: Both of these are the element, they're just different ways of showing it.